# How to upload DataGrid

Tags: c#, database, datagrid

My `application` collects `data` from `mail`, then stores it in DB, displays it and works with it in `DataGrid`. Always the originals, no duplicates. But I would like that every time a new object is saved, it is displayed directly in `DataGrid` without any. How to achieve this?
It works only if I am for example will click on button, then it Loads

Once the window is created

```
 public AdminWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadAlertGrid();
            Task.Run(() => Test(new EmailParser(true, "abc", "defg")));
           
    }
```

Method, where I am `extracting data` and save them if they don't exist in DB already

```
 public void Test(EmailParser emailParser)
        {
            bool help = true;

            do
            {

                using (var client = new ImapClient())
                {
                    using (var cancel = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource())
                    {

                        client.Connect(emailParser.ServerName, emailParser.Port, emailParser.IsSSLuse,
                            cancel.Token);

                        client.Authenticate(emailParser.Username, emailParser.Password, cancel.Token);

                        var inbox = client.Inbox;
                        inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);
                   
                        for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                            GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
                            Problem problem = new Problem(message.MessageId);
                            if (!dAOProblem.GetAll().Any(x => x.Message_Id.Equals(problem.Message_Id)))
                            {
                                dAOProblem.Save(problem);
                                Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1, problem.Id);
                                if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(alert.Id_MimeMessage)))
                                {
                                    dAOAlert.Save(alert);
                                    LoadAlertGrid();
                                }

                            }

                        }

                        //client.Disconnect(true, cancel.Token);
                    }
                }

            } while (help != false);

        }
```

Method, where I am trying to `Load DataGrid`

```
   public void LoadAlertGrid()
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseSingleton.connString);
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Alert.email ,Alert.date , AMUser.name as 'admin', Problem.nameOfAlert, [Value].[value] , Result.result FROM Alert JOIN AMUser ON Alert.AMUser_ID = AMUser.id JOIN Problem ON Alert.Problem_ID = Problem.id JOIN[Value] ON Problem.Value_ID = [Value].id JOIN Result ON Problem.Result_ID = Result.id ; ", conn))
            {
                using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        table.Load(sdr);
                        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(dAOAlert.GetAll(), alertLock);
                        lock (alertLock)
                        {
                            AlertTable.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                        }
                        sdr.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Are those two functions executed by the same programm? Who calls the function "test"? You could use a BackgroundWorker or a Timer to load the DataGrid periodically. But you could also set a flag on the function "Test" if a new mail is arrived.

Comment: @ThomasKlammer I have edited my question. Is better now?

Comment: @jiirina so the emailparser only runs once the window is started?

Comment: @ThomasKlammer No, in `Test()` method, code runs in `do-while` loop

Comment: Please provide that code too

Comment: I have provide it, please look at the `Test()` method again

Comment: Sorry, did not see that. Do you get an error message running your code?

Comment: @ThomasKlammer Its okay, no I didn't get any kind of error message

Comment: it's very hard to identify the problem with your code. I don't see anything where the datatable is bound to the datagrid. please provide your code as detailed as possible

Comment: @ThomasKlammer Here is `DataTable` bound with `DataGrid` `AlertTable.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Threads. Different Thread owned method `Test()`

I have solved to adding `Dispatcher` and `Invoke()` like this for `ItemSource`
of `DataGrid`:

```
 this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            AlertTable.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                        });
```